# How to use left outer join in django?

Tags: sql, django, database, left-join

I have Two Models

```
class Business(models.Model):
    BID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=datetime.now().strftime("%d%y%H%S%m%M%f"))
    BusinessName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ContactPerson = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class BusinessComment(models.Model):
    BID = models.ForeignKey(Business, blank=True, null=True)
    Rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class BusinessHours(models.Model):
    BID = models.ForeignKey(Business, blank=True, null=True)
    Day = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    StartHour = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
    EndHour = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want access in single object below values from both models.this concept is left outer join but can I achieve in single object that have all values as below.

```
BID,BusinessName,ContactPerson,AVG(Rating),Count(Number of Comment) (Condition is Business.BID = BusinessComment.BID)
```

Business Table Data

```
BID BusinessName    ContactPerson
1   First            First
2   Second           Second
```

BusinessHours Table Data

```
id    BID   Rating  Comment
1      1    3      Comment1
2      1    5      Comment2
3      2    4      Comment3
4      2    5      Comment4
```

Then result Should be in Object As:

```
BID Businame ContactPerson Rating Comment
1    First      First        4      2
2    Second      Second      4.5     2
```

I have tried many times but I'm Unable to do that.P

**EDIT :**

```
 today = datetime.datetime.today().weekday() + 1
```

BusinessHours Table Data

```
 id BID Day  Stathours EndHour        
145 1   1   12:00am 12:00am
146 1   2   Closed  Closed
147 1   3   12:00am 12:00am
148 1   4   Closed  Closed
149 1   5   12:00am 12:00am
150 1   6   12:00am 12:00am
151 1   7   12:00am 12:00am
152 2   1   12:00am 12:00am
153 2   2   12:00am 12:00am
154 2   3   12:00am 12:00am
155 2   4   12:00am 12:00am
156 2   5   12:00am 12:00am
157 2   6   12:00am 12:00am
158 2   7   12:00am 12:00am
```

Now I want to filter data from BusinessHours using `filter(BusinessHours.Day = today)` with annotate.So that output will be as below.

```
 BID Businame ContactPerson Rating Comment StartHour  EndHours
    1    First      First        4      2    12:00am  12:00pm
    2    Second      Second      4.5     2   12:00am  12:00pm
```

StartHour and EndHour is give value of Current Day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [annotation with aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Avg

qs = Business.objcts.annotate(comment_count=Count('businesscomment'), 
                              avg_rating=Avg('businesscomment__rating'))
```

And, then in the queryset you can access the `comment_count` or `avg_rating`:

```
# I am using these fields in values_list for example
qs.values_list('BID', 'BusinessName', 'ContactPerson', 'comment_count', 'avg_rating')
```

Comment: Can you tell me one thing .How can I use filter in annotate method.Example is that I want also get rating that BusinessHours.id=1

Comment: Is `BusinessHours` another model ?

Comment: Each Business has 7 day record means day rows according to day 1,2 etc, So I want to access particular day StartHour and EndHour in that object

Comment: Please add the model to your question. It is really not readable here.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking in the edited part. I would suggest that you post a separate question on SO with proper details since it is a different question altogether.

Comment: See again my Editing plz